# Spinner initialized when my activity starts - Android

Tags: android, spinner

I have Spinner which name: turListe. It gets input values from database. When i start my activity, onOtemSelected starts automatically. How can i solve this problem?

```
turListe.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            String turAdi;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreen.this, TarifListe.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            turAdi = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            bundle.putString("turad", turAdi);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem. I believe one possible workaround is the set the adapter on the spinner before you call `setOnItemSelectedListener()`.

If this isn't possible then you could have a Boolean such as `isAdapterSet` and have your `onItemSelected()` method check it to see if it should ignore the selection event or not.

Comment: is there any property available like isAdapterSet ?

Comment: No. Just create your own and have it as `false` to begin with. Then set it to `true` the first time the user selects an item from the `Spinner`.

Comment: I call setAdapter before setOnItemSelectedListener, yet onItemSelected is still called.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using a button next to the related spinner. I know it isn't a perfect solution, but it solved my problem in a short time.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I solved it with a boolen flag as static in global declaration.

```
MyOnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener = new MyOnItemSelectedListener(false);
sp_choose1.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
sp_choose2.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
onItemSelectedListener.getDataforList();
```

Use this class and toggle the boolean to enable or disable the onItemSelectedListener calls.

```
private class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public MyOnItemSelectedListener(boolean bool){
            spinner_bug = bool;
        }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +
                    parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(spinner_bug)
                getDataforList();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }

        private void getDataforList(){  
                  //dosomething
                }
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use only OnItemSelectedListener() instead of AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()